# How read QPointF in C++ without Qt libraries?

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I have to read a .ini file which contains some sample values like:

```
[Category]
key1="@Variant(\0\0\0\x1a@Q\x13v\x8a\xf1\xfd\xf@=#lSm\xa9\xee)"
key2=1
key3=1
```

The value of `key1` is a binary format of QPointF from Qt framework.
So the value of `key1` is a QPointF stored as QVariant.
This value can be read (with Qt libraries) with:

```
QSettings->value( "Category/key1" ).toPointF()
```

How can I achieve the same result without Qt using only C++ std and boost libraries?

More informations about QPointF are showed here:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpointf.html

Comment: You could always store the x/y/z/whatever values separately, in plain text: `key1=1;2;3`

Comment: I advicse you to use the Qt 4.8 source code, located at http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt.git/tree/src/corelib/kernel regarding `QVariant`'s. Right now I can't find the exact conversion code, but with a proper IDE, havinf the Qt 4.8 tree loaded, it should be easy to find the necessary definitions. `QVariant` itself is a template class, for which coversions to and from certain types are defined, some explicitly via specialization, some not.

Comment: Use Qt or don't use Qt's serialization format in your ini exchange format

Comment: Also, another possibility is to create a small utility using Qt to parse the data and convert it into the desired format. From what I understand, such a conversion will only take place once during the config file migration?